# SQL Data Reader SQL Server core implementation

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, algorithm, performance

while i am learning core of `System.Data` i tried reading [MSDN](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs) Core implementation code.

in the same way i could call some low level system dll (win32) to read hdd drive
info i was trying to test and learn from system data SQL through the above MSDN link, as i am trying to break it down i couldn't find the entry point.
my question is:

**what is the minimal code required to connect to SQL SERVER and return some data ?**

*either with `c#` <sub>preferred</sub> or `c++` (if there's noticeably less overhead)

**Edit:**
using only some parts From the `System.Data` `SqlDataReader` Rather than whole class.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  I read it three times and am still unsure what you're asking.

Comment: @Stan, thanks, i have edited it(take a look), i will try harder

Comment: now your question makes sense, but this forum isn't intended for people to provide you with code.  You're supposed to post what you've tried and explain what you want to happen, explain what is happening, and ask for help.  This post can roughly be translated into "Write code for me that connects to SQL server"

Answer (score 1):

System.Data.SqlClient (.NET Provider for SQL Server) is a low-level "DLL".  It communicates with SQL Server using the low-level TDS protocol similarly to ODBC and OLEDB.  The difference is SqlClient is a managed provider whereas ODBC drivers and OLEDB providers are native (unmanaged).  The unmanaged driver/providers provide a call-level interface and COM interface respectively, which is intended to be used from native code like unmanaged C++.

All these providers/drivers communicate with SQL Server using the low-level TDS protocol.  The TDS protocol itself is not directly exposed.  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader is the lowest level data access from managed code and provides the highest performance for .NET applications.

Comment: A link to the [TDS specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) in case the OP does want to go down the route of writing his own client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the beginner's guide to connecting to SQL Server with C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

But you should make sure to properly separate code-responsibility so that you're not rewriting the same code all over the place.  Have a class that interfaces with the database (dataaccess layer) so you can just call it from all of your business objects and static classes.

Comment: thank you for quickly posting an answer, my intention was going to the lower level part of the communication with SQL SERVER (2008/2012), and not via using SqlClinet as a whole, if there's any such way.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're trying to do, now.  I assume it's possible, although I don't know offhand and wasn't able to quickly find it with a Google search.  Why are you trying to avoid using SqlClient?

Comment: regarding your second comment on my question i am not asking for a code that will complete an ORM , i just wish to start a "Hand Shake" with the server, the base function of the reader to accomplish login and say give me some data from a table or call a stored procedure, how does the `DataReader` gets to say "give me" without all the other irrelevant to that minimal task members in the class

Comment: _Why are you trying to avoid using SqlClient_ : i am trying to test my own way to query data , say i want to return a `bit` yes /no i want to use my own implementation for minimal interaction with SQL SERVER

Comment: i think this is a start (: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the ODBC SQL connections.  However, I would suggest using the built-in SQL classes - the overhead of which is rendered negligible by modern processing power.  I can't think of an environment that has SQL server but lacks the necessary processing power to use these classes.